# Linking to boost

Tags: c++, opencv, boost, ros, point-cloud-library

I am trying to link to the boost libraries for a ros node, in connection I found the following links: "[How to include external library (boost) into CLion C++ project with CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28761323/how-to-include-external-library-boost-into-clion-c-project-with-cmake?noredirect=1&lq=1)" and "[How to link C++ program with Boost using CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897839/how-to-link-c-program-with-boost-using-cmake)" and "[problem building in groovy with catkin and boost](http://answers.ros.org/question/60489/problem-building-in-groovy-with-catkin-and-boost/)".

As a result I create my CMakelists.txt as follows which needs to use OpenCV and Boost:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(image_listener_rosbag)

#set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF) 
#set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)  
#set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF) 
## Find catkin macros and libraries
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  image_transport
  message_generation
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
)

add_message_files(
  FILES
)
generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
  sensor_msgs
)

catkin_package(
    CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime
)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

find_package( Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS serialization archive ) # is this correct?
# The components included are chosen because I need to use the following usings: 
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/split_free.hpp>

include_directories(
    ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})

add_library(image_listener_rosbag src/image_listener.cpp)
add_dependencies(image_listener_rosbag ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
add_executable(image_listener_rosbag_node src/image_listener.cpp)
target_link_libraries(image_listener_rosbag_node ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})#
```

When I try to build it suddenly another package relying on PCL crashes with:

```
 -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/johann/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/johann/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

Looking into the `CMakeError.log` Complains about not finding `pthread_create`. The PCL package that crashes has no reference to boost other than what PCL has inside. Should I add boost explicitly in the failing package as above? **Tried:** adding the information about boost from above to the PCL node, I get the same error log referencing the missing `pthread_create`.

As a test I have tried editing the code above in several ways if remove all the boost references from the code above, both packages are build and runs with no issue.

If I remove `find_package(Boost ...` I receive a lot of issues like: undefined reference to boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive::~basic_oarchive()` But the PCL node compiles fine with no issue.

**Question:** Am I adding boost correctly and the libraries?
If so is there some issue when including PCL in another package that you need a special reference?

**System:** For reference I am implementing it using ros indigo full, with the included opencv(2.4) and pcl(looks like 1.54 libraries), everything is on Ubuntu 14.04.

**Extra**

This question, "[PCL install links directly to boost installation directory somehow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23485903/pcl-install-links-directly-to-boost-installation-directory-somehow?rq=1)", seems to have some of the same issues I have however not been able to transfer the suggestions yet.

**PCL node**

The below node is the one exhibiting the error when the boost includes are added above.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(pointcloudlistener)

find_package(PCL REQUIRED)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  image_transport
  PCL
  pcl_ros
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
)

add_message_files(
  FILES
)

generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
  sensor_msgs
)

catkin_package( 
 CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime
)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(PCL REQUIRED)

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

link_directories(
    ${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS}
)

add_library(pointcloudlistener src/pcl_listener.cpp src/matPclConverter.cpp src/Image_Safety.cpp)
add_dependencies(pointcloudlistener ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

add_executable(pointcloudlistener_node src/pcl_listener.cpp src/matPclConverter.cpp src/Image_Safety.cpp)
target_link_libraries(pointcloudlistener_node ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: your CMakeLists doesen't mention PCL in anyway ? so which PCL node ?

Comment: @Vtik no it does not, the pcl node is  another node which works completely. However when I add boost to the nose described above the pcl node fails. That is why I draw that into the question. Therefore firstly my question is if the above is the correct way to add boost, to try and limit the issue size.

Comment: well, looks like PCL is nevertheless linked to the issue and it won't help without posting the full CMakeLists. without it, we wouldn't be able to reproduce the error, so a bit lengthy is worth it ...

Comment: @Vtik Sorry thank you for looking at the question. I have now added the requested CMakelists.txt

Comment: If it is really pthread_create error, add to your `target_link_libraries` `pthread` and `rt`, but it will be nice to see some more lines in your output before the error, and some lines from your log

Comment: The comment above, but instead of hardcoding platform-dependent threading libraries, use `find_package(Threads REQUIRED); target_link_libraries(... ${Threads_LIBRARIES})`.
Also, remove that extra `find_package(catkin REQUIRED)`!